# De-Serialize generic nested type with Dynamic Property name

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

I get below JSON object as a response:

```
{
    status: false,
    employee: {
        firstName: "Test",
        lastName: "Test_Last"
    }
}
```

As the above string is an API response, "Employee" here is the dynamic property. It could be either User or Company etc..

So to deserialize the above object in C#, I created a class structure something like this:

```
public class Response<T> {

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "status")]
    public bool Status {get;set;}

    public T Item {get;set;}

}

[JsonObject(Title = "employee")]
public class Employee {

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "firstName")]
    public string FirstName {get; set;}

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "lastName")]
    public string LastName {get; set;}

}
```

But when I try to deserialize the JSON string, Employee class is not deserialized and the value of the employee object always remains null.

This is how I deserialize the JSON string:

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response<Employee>>(jsonString);
```

I believe I am doing something wrong on JsonObject attribute of Employee class. But I am not sure.

Comment: That's because with your code JSON.Net expects there to be a property `item`. You need a custom contract resolver: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ContractResolver.htm

Comment: The crux is *the desire to have to have the property name 'employee' (or 'user') be dynamic wrt the type*, not the nested type itself.

Comment: It is solvable, just use the contract resolver and use e.g. class name or that 'json object title' attribute to pull it out.

Comment: Consider to [edit] question to show examples of the data (more than one). If you don't need huge variety of choices it may be easier to use regular serialization to intermediate object that looks like ({status, employee, user, company}) and then map them back to list of items you want with `(status, item) = (status, employee??user??company)`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have `JObjectAttribute` set for the expected Type as shown in the example OP code , You could use a Custom `DefaultContractResolver`  . For example,

```
public class GenericContractResolver<T> : DefaultContractResolver  
{

    protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        var property = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);
        if (property.UnderlyingName == nameof(Response<T>.Item))
        {
            foreach( var attribute in System.Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(T)))
            {
                if(attribute is JsonObjectAttribute jobject)
                {
                    property.PropertyName = jobject.Title;
                }
            }
        }
        return property;
    }
}
```

Usage

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response<Employee>>(json,
                                           new JsonSerializerSettings 
                                           { 
                                             ContractResolver = new GenericContractResolver<Employee>() 
                                           });
```

[**Demo Code**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/nxsNL3)

Comment: From the question: _"As the above string is an API response, "Employee" here is the dynamic property. It could be either User or Company etc.."_

Comment: @John I hav the same doubt and if the property itself dynamic ( As of now the property name is "Employee" and later it would be change to any other name so if it consider this as dynamically changed property name ) then how we can handle this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely go the ContractResolver way. They help when you need specialized serialization. Here's an article written by Brian Oliver explaining how to use them. His example is pretty close to what you might be looking for.
https://www.c2experience.com/blog/using-custom-contract-resolvers-for-jsonnet